# Why am I getting “Too many positionals passed…” in this call to HTTP::Request.new?

Tags: raku

I tried six or so variations on this code and excepting hardcoded `Str`s like `GET => …` I always got this error. Why? How can I fix it and understand it? Is it a bug in the HTTP::Request code?

Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use HTTP::UserAgent; # Installed today with panda, for HTTP::Request.

HTTP::Request.new( GET => "/this/is/fine" ).WHICH.say;

# First, check that yes, they are there.
say %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD>, " ", %*ENV<REQUEST_URI>; 

# This and single value or slice combination always errors-
HTTP::Request.new( %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD>, %*ENV<REQUEST_URI> );
```

Output with invariable error

```
$ env REQUEST_METHOD=GET REQUEST_URI=/ SOQ.p6
HTTP::Request|140331166709152
GET /
Too many positionals passed; expected 1 argument but got 3
  in method new at lib/HTTP/Request.pm6:13
  in block <unit> at ./SOQ.p6:11
```

HTTP::Request is from this package — https://github.com/sergot/http-useragent/ — Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't the last line read `HTTP::Request.new( %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD> => %*ENV<REQUEST_URI> );`? In Perl6, `=>` is not sugar for a comma, but the pair constructor

Comment: @Christoph, thanks but that is one of the many variations I tried that failed with the same error; just double checked. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
HTTP::Request.new(|{ %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD> => %*ENV<REQUEST_URI> });
```

instead of the more obvious

```
HTTP::Request.new( %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD> => %*ENV<REQUEST_URI> );
```

If the left-hand side of `=>` isn't a literal, we won't bind to a named parameter. Instead, a pair object gets passed as positional argument.

To work around this, we construct an anonymous hash that gets flattened into the argument list via prefix `|`.

As a bonus, here are some more creative ways to do it:

```
HTTP::Request.new(|%( %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD REQUEST_URI> ));
HTTP::Request.new(|[=>] %*ENV<REQUEST_METHOD REQUEST_URI> );
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I dislike that the regular/nude comma and slice versions don’t Just Work™…